# Load the same Surface View in two different layout files

Tags: android

I need to load the same `Surface View` in two different layout files.

I tried to do this, but the error:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already have a parent. You must call removeView () on the child's parent first".

If one of the `removeView()`, can not achieve the purpose.

Is there any good solution?

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);//The parent of CameraPreview is SurfaceView
LinearLayout linearLayoutleft = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camrea_preview_left);
LinearLayout linearLayoutright = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camrea_preview_rigth);
linearLayoutleft.addView(mPreview);
linearLayoutright.addView(mPreview);
```

Comment: No. As the error suggests, a view can not have multiple parents. You will either have to manage two views or move it around between parents.

Comment: Thank you！ your answer is very helpful to me.